# Struct declaration before definition

Tags: c++, class, struct, forward-declaration

I have a small issue with my C++ code.

```
class Command {
public:
    virtual void start(CommandDesc userinput, Converter* convertobj) = 0;
    virtual void help(int option) = 0;
};


struct CommandDesc
{
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    Command* comobj;   //Issue is here
};
```

If I define the structure before the class, I won't be able to define a member

```
Command* comobj;
```

If I define after the class, I wont be able to pass instance of struct to method with

```
virtual void start(CommandDesc userinput, Converter* convertobj) = 0;
```

What can you suggest? Is there any way to first declare the structure, than define it separately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Ok, if I define the structure before the class, I won't be able to
>   define a member
>
> ```
> Command* comobj;
> ```

Since comobj is a pointer, you can forward declare `Command` to resolve this.

You'd do this:

```
class Command;

struct CommandDesc
{
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    Command* comobj; 
};

class Command {
public:
    virtual void start(CommandDesc userinput, Converter* convertobj) = 0;
    virtual void help(int option) = 0;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for a solution, I will try, but just curious, if it wasn't a pointer, why would it fail?

Comment: @khajvah when declare a member, it's type must be complete. Pointer can point to incomplete type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - simple - forward declaration

Just put

```
class Command;

struct CommandDesc
{

 ....

}

class Command {
 As before

};
```